# Making a GET request in R (REST API)

Tags: r, api, http, curl

Need to make a REST API request in R via get with header to get data. Swagger: https://apitradedoc.currency.com/swagger-ui.html#/rest-api/accountUsingGET

```
library(curl)
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
username <- "api-key"
password <- "secret key"
timestamp <- round(as.numeric(Sys.time()),0)
base <- "https://api-adapter.backend.currency.com"
accountInfo <- "/api/v1/account"
url <- paste0(base,accountInfo)
res <- GET(url = url, add_headers('X-MBX-APIKEY' = username), query = list('signature' = password, 'timestamp' = timestamp))
```

The code should work but it gives an error status 400

Comment: Have you tried to put `'signature' = password, 'timestamp' = timestamp` in `add_headers`?

Comment: @Rui Barradas Yes, same result as previously